# Is it possible to generate Azure ARM templates from code?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

AWS has AWS CDK which allows defining and synthesizing Cloudformation templates in a programming language. Is there any similar SDK solution for ARM templates? I know Azure have built Bicep which is an abstraction of ARM templates, however Bicep doesn't seem to have an SDK.

I'm looking for an officially supported workflow (so no github community contributions).

Comment: Have you checked the Azure SDKs that exist for many languages? Similarly to AWS CDK you can create, list, delete Azure resources with them using generic code.

Comment: @ChristianVorhemus Does that allow defining an ARM template and synthesizing it to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you would find for this would be something like using the CDK with terraform to write Azure resources.
Which actually has a post on hashicorp blog:
https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/building-azure-resources-with-typescript-using-the-cdk-for-terraform

Comment: Yeah, but that's for synthesizing terraform config files, not ARM templates right?

Comment: Correct. As aside from Bicep there is nothing else (I've been searching a bit longer, but no result). So you're stuck with other tooling to handle it in a different way.

Comment: So in the end, if you realy need something like this: you'll either use the third party tool which does it differently, or you're gonna create something custom to fill your need.

Comment: Yeah; I'm stuck manipulating JSON for now. Thanks for your answer; I'll wait a few more days to see if other answers come in, otherwise I'll give you the bounty